# tcl pause & waiting for key pressed to continue

Tags: key, tcl, pressed

I'm looking for a way in tcl to pause the script (for example after some outputs with "puts") and wait for a key pressed from the user before continuing to output the remaining text.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to build that into the script? Someone might want to send the output to a file or pipe it to `grep`, `sed` or whatever. A better solution is to pipe the scripts output to one of the programs `more` (available on Windows too) or `less`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With gratitude to Hai Vu's answer, if you're on a unix-like system with [`stty`](http://man.cx/stty)

```
proc anykey {{msg "Hit any key: "}} {
    set stty_settings [exec stty -g]
    exec stty raw -echo
    puts -nonewline $msg
    flush stdout
    read stdin 1
    exec stty $stty_settings
    puts ""
}
puts 1
anykey
puts 2
```

Link to thorough discussion on Tcl wiki: [Reading a single character from the keyboard using Tcl](http://wiki.tcl.tk/14693)

Comment: Doing the same thing on Windows requires using the TWAPI package so that you can change the terminal mode. It's a [little long for a comment](http://wiki.tcl.tk/14693).

Comment: Extra note: if you want to a key this way more than once, `stty -icanon` has the desired effect, but is not a severe as `stty raw` - e.g. it lets the user quit using `^C` as usual.

Answer (score 16):

You just use `gets` to read from stdin:

```
proc pause {{message "Hit Enter to continue ==> "}} {
    puts -nonewline $message
    flush stdout
    gets stdin
}

pause "Hurry, hit enter: "; # Sample usage 1
pause;                      # Sample usage 2, use default message
```

Comment: +1 for your Answer. Beautiful code provided. After seeing your answer, 1 question came to my mind.. What if i want user to "press any key"? not just "Enter"... Is such thing possible? I would have started this question as a new thread, but was not confident for such scenario.. Is there any option/way?

Comment: thank you for this short code, it works very well with enter key.

Answer (score 0):

A potential solution for Windows:

```
exec -ignorestderr [file join $env(windir) system32 cmd.exe] /c pause
```

This notices non-ascii keypresses, too (such as arrow keys, Escape etc.).

Another solution is the [Raw Mode on Windows](http://wiki.tcl.tk/14693) proposed by 
Donal Fellows [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993122/tcl-pause-waiting-for-key-pressed-to-continue#comment28077663_19003443)
 (thanks for the link!), which can be summarized into
these two lines of code:

```
twapi::modify_console_input_mode stdin -lineinput 0 -echoinput 0
read stdin 1
```

This does not notice Escape, arrows keys and the like (and you may need to restore the console input mode later).