# How to prevent tcl script from exiting?

Tags: tcl

I am running `tclsh some.tcl` and it exits after it hits eof. I want it not to exit and gives control to user for interaction. *Note that we can do this by invoking shell and sourcing script but that doesn't solve my problem as it cannot be used in automation.*

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993122/tcl-pause-waiting-for-key-pressed-to-continue

Comment: **Not a duplicate.** This question is about entering a command loop, not just waiting for a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can load the [TclX package](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tclx8.2/TclX.n.html) (old but still useful) then you can do:

```
package require Tclx; # Lower case at the end for historical reasons

# Your stuff here

commandloop
```

That's very much like how Tcl's own interactive command line works.

---

Otherwise, here's a scripted version that does *most* of what an interactive command session does:

```
if {![info exists tcl_prompt1]} {
    set tcl_prompt1 {puts -nonewline "% ";flush stdout}
}
if {![info exists tcl_prompt2]} {
    # Note that tclsh actually defaults to not printing anything for this prompt
    set tcl_prompt2 {puts -nonewline "> ";flush stdout}
}

set script ""
set prompt $tcl_prompt1
while {![eof stdin]} {
    eval $prompt;                        # Print the prompt by running its script
    if {[gets stdin line] >= 0} {
        append script $line "\n";        # The newline is important
        if {[info complete $script]} {   # Magic! Parse for syntactic completeness
            if {[catch $script msg]} {   # Evaluates the script and catches the result
                puts stderr $msg
            } elseif {$msg ne ""} {      # Don't print empty results
                puts stdout $msg
            }
            # Accumulate the next command
            set script ""
            set prompt $tcl_prompt1
        } else {
            # We have a continuation line
            set prompt $tcl_prompt2
        }
    }
}
```

Getting the remaining bits right (e.g., the interaction with the event loop when the Tk package is loaded) would require quite a bit more complexity...